# UrlHelperExtensions.Page Method for Areas

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-mvc-areas

## How can one include an Area in the UrlHelperExtensions.Page Method?

The [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.urlhelperextensions.page?view=aspnetcore-2.2) don't mention areas.

When I want to link to a page in an area (in my case Identity) the page name is not found:

```
var callbackUrl = Url.Page(
            "/Identity/Account/ResetPassword",
            pageHandler: null,
            values: new {code},
            protocol: Request.Scheme);
```

callback is null and I don't know how to specify that the page is outside of my normal Razor Pages Pages-Folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation on this is very poor. You can specify the area inside your values like this:

```
var callbackUrl = Url.Page(
        "/Identity/Account/ResetPassword",
        pageHandler: null,
        values: new { code, area = "Identity" },
        protocol: Request.Scheme);
```

Comment: Weird but my generated url from above code is as follows:

https://localhost:44346/?area=Identity&code=CfDJ8OZvPv5w8uZOu6N%2F9ZZs6M6acPTC44cfIzoWbKWavmOoETCDq1FntmC%2FfhltzqyfHHP1015wHVRoChFrkq7sjEW8CAYAMkn4hroyFDAMPmdPNRAKitbujWKcHfVQs9bEWPXk%2Fq2iIgLWsZWm9k%2Fs%2BWbtehMB%2BCQimdR17dAcgT3YHnE5w569OltZFArdgZPmvA%3D%3D&page=%2FIdentity%2FAccount%2FResetPassword